# Why mx.text showing fuzzy text?

Tags: apache-flex, image-processing, text, flex3, blur

```
<mx:HBox width="100%" height = "100%" textAlign="left" verticalAlign="top" paddingTop="0">
    <mx:Text text="{text}" height = "100%" width="100%" fontSize="11" color="{color}" paddingTop="-20"/>
</mx:HBox>
```

I have this HBox inside a TitleWindow.  I'm not sure why the text are blurred...

Using:
Flex3.6v10.0.0
FB4

Comment: Do you have any CSS applied to the text component? Are you using an embedded font?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot or code sample?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your `height` and `width` attributes in your Text tag.  The font might be getting stretched.